# Android: Icon in menu not showing like it should

Tags: android, xml, menu, icons, show

I'm using a custom menu for my bottom navigation. But my second icon is not what it should be...

How it shows

[image: how it is]

What it should be

[image]

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_overview"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/overzicht"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_modifies"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/nieuw2"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:visible="true" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_create"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/create"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_profile"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/profiel"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

It's weird that all my icons are working expect the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Icons are supposed to be all one color but you actually have two colors in your image.

See how the side of the triangle at the upper left is green in your image but white in the menu?  Your green pixels are being tinted white, the same color as your background, so you don't see them.

If you really want a "negative" image like this, my recommendation would be to take all the green pixels that are surrounded by white pixels and make them transparent.  That way the background green will show through and it will look like you expect.

While you're at it, you might as well change those upper triangle pixels from green to white, since they will be tinted white anyways.